# Flv to mp4 conversion

Tags: android, flv, mp4

I want to play the flv files in Android. So what I thought is to convert the flv file to mp4 or 3gp(for which there is a decoder in Android). OpenCore can be used to convert. I have looked into opencore code, there is a class in opencore "/android/external/opencore/fileformats/mp4/composer" to create the mp4 file. It has apis like

```
AddTrack 
AddSampleToTrack
```

I should give the input as frames, but in Flv I will get the Sorenson Video and Mp3 audio frame(after doing some trivial string operations to remove the headers). Can I use these directly as input to above apis or is there any good way to convert flv to mp4? And also I have looked into "/android/external/opencore/nodes/pvmp4ffcomposernode" but it reads from ports not able to know how to send input to this class.

Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You want to convert on the device itself??

Comment: I agree with Shay. Video conversion on a mobile device is going to be nasty, brutish, and slow.

Comment: Yes, it is a local file i.e., no need to download just conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved using ffmpeg.
I have ported ffmpeg and libfaac to Android. It works great.

Comment: Is it available as application? That will be great to watch downloaded flv on Android