# I need the Flv converter from swf and mp4 files

Tags: flash, flv, converters, mp4

I need the flv converter from swf and mp4 files without any of the website logo or any watermarks.

Please suggest some websites

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049918/flv-to-mp4-conversion

Answer (score 4):

One thing I can tell you is **don't** go to `www.brothersoft.com`. Every time I need something for audio or video conversion I make the mistake of going there, and all I get is:

1. A worm that requires me to rebuild from an image.
2. My entire codec set replaced and screwed to heck.
3. A half-baked software that requires a 50 dollar purchase before you can output anything.

Sorry I can't tell you anything positive, but hopefully I just saved you some heartache.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you're asking for a flv converter to use withing your program right?

In case you're using .NET frameworks check this website:
http://www.dominion-web.com/applications/flvconverter/download.php it costs around 40 bucks and does the job nicely. Since its a .NET library, you don't even have to envelop it in code

you can also try http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg/

I've never used it myself, but seems nice enough, its free and opensource.

Comment: Thanks. But Could you tell me some for free download?